# Probability inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are independent random variables such that $P(X_i=v_i)=1/v_i$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-1/v_i$, where $1\leq v_i\leq n+1$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. I want to prove that $P(X_1+X_2+...+X_n\geq n+1)\leq 1-(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$

I thought it this way:
$P(X_1+X_2+...+X_n\geq n+1)\leq P(n\max\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}\geq n+1)=1-(1-\frac{1}{v_1})(1-\frac{1}{v_2})...(1-\frac{1}{v_n}).$ Since $1\leq v_i \leq n+1$ for all $i=1,2,...,n.$ Then the minimum at the right side of the inequality is obtained for $v_i=n+1$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$. I think I must consider the maximum of the right side (which is equal to 1), and not the minimum.

Comment: There appear to be some notational/typing errors in your first paragraph please check carefully

Comment: e.g. First you need to give the range on $i$ there in the first paragraph, not in your thoughts on how to tackle the problem. Second you need to fix the probability for the zero case. Thirdly, if the "$x_i$" are predetermined constants you should try to avoid using the lower-case version of the symbols for the random variables (since conventionally that's used for the values taken by the realization of the random variables) but some other symbol (e.g. $v_i$ or $d_i$ might do, but you'd start with "Let $v_i,\, i=1, 2, \ldots, n$ be a set of positive constants such that $\sum_i v_i<1$, say) -etc

Comment: what values can $X$ take ?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 The values are implied by the problem statement: for the probabilities to be valid, all the $v_i$ must be $1$ or greater (and, explicitly, no greater than $n+1$).  There are no other implied restrictions.